# SQL Server XML multi-level query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following xml that I need to query:

```sql
declare @xml xml = '<root>
    <level1>
        <property1>Value1</property1>
        <property2>Value2</property2>
        <level2List>
            <level2>Child1</level2>
            <level2>Child2</level2>
        </level2List>
    </level1>
    <level1>
        <property1>Value3</property1>
        <property2>Value4</property2>
        <level2List>
            <level2>Child3</level2>
            <level2>Child4</level2>
        </level2List>
    </level1>
</root>'
```

And I need the following result:

```
Property1 Property2 Child
Value1    Value2    Child1
Value1    Value2    Child2
Value3    Value4    Child3
Value3    Value4    Child4
```

I have this query:

```
select col.value('Property1','varchar(100)') Property1,
       col.value('Property2','varchar(100)') Property2
from @xml.nodes('//root/level1') as tab(col)
```

But I can't figure out how to join a parent node with its children. Any idea?

Comment: I don't think your XML is formatted that way.  According to this example, `level2List`, `Property1`, and `property2` are sister nodes under the `Level` node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start searching from the bottom:

```
DECLARE @xml AS XML = '<root>
    <level1>
        <property1>Value1</property1>
        <property2>Value2</property2>
        <level2List>
            <level2>Child1</level2>
            <level2>Child2</level2>
        </level2List>
    </level1>
    <level1>
        <property1>Value3</property1>
        <property2>Value4</property2>
        <level2List>
            <level2>Child3</level2>
            <level2>Child4</level2>
        </level2List>
    </level1>
</root>';

SELECT
    n.value('../../property1[1]','varchar(100)') property1,
    n.value('../../property2[1]','varchar(100)') property2,
    n.value('.','varchar(100)') Child
FROM @xml.nodes('//level1//level2') AS x(n)
```

Or by extending your original attempt:

```
FROM @xml.nodes('//level1') AS n1(l1)
CROSS APPLY l1.nodes('.//level2') AS n2(l2)
```

Comment: Good +1, trying to notice differences between this and mine. The biggest is `x(n)` instead of `N(X)` :)

Answer (score 2):

I would use following:

```
SELECT
    X.value('(../../property1)[1]', 'varchar(20)') Property1,
    X.value('(../../property2)[1]', 'varchar(20)') Property2,
    X.value('.', 'varchar(20)') Child
FROM @xml.nodes('//level2') N(X)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `APPLY` :

```
SELECT col.value('property1[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS property1,
       col.value('property2[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS property2,
       col1.value('text()[1]','varchar(100)') AS Child
FROM @xml.nodes('root/level1') AS tab(col) OUTER APPLY 
     col.nodes('level2List/level2') tab1(col1);
```